# Extracting voice of different speakers in overlapping speech using pyannote

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, voice-recognition, diarization

I am using Pyannote for speaker diarization. I am able to get the overlapping speech's start and end time but not able to do voice separation. Is there a way to use Pyannote for voice separation?
If not, please suggest some way to do voice separation.